# Limpiar input formulario modal bootstrap cuando se presiona botón Cancelar

Tags: html, jquery, bootstrap

Tengo una pantalla inicial de bienvenida con un botón que llama a un formulario modal. Cuando se despliega el formulario modal, puedo ingresar el nombre de usuario y su password, pero si en ves de presionar el botón Aceptar presiono el botón Cancelar, el formulario se cierra. Si ahora vuelvo a llamar el formulario modal, se despliega con los dos input con los datos ingresados en la vez anterior. Por favor, me pueden indicar cómo puedo limpiar estos input

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#login').on('shown.bs.modal', function() {
        $('#usuario').focus();
        $("#login").reset();
    });
})
```

```html
<?php
 session_start();
?>
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<style>
    .fondo {
        background: #333;
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        background-size: cover;
    }    
    .alto {
        height: 100vh;
    }
</style>
<head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <script defer src="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.6/js/all.js"></script>
    <!-- <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/2215372ade.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script> -->
</head>
<body>
    <!--PANTALLA INICIAL DEL SISTEMA-->
    <div class="container-fluid fondo">
        <div class="row alto align-items-center justify-content-center text-center text-ligth text-white">
            <div class="col-m-8">
                <div class="display-4">
                    <i class="fas fa-spinner fa-spin"></i>
                </div>
                <h1 class="display-4 my-3">SIGED</h1>
                <p class="lead mb-4">Sistema Integrado de Gestión Educacional</p>
                <hr class="bg-light">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-light mx-2" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#login">Ingresar</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- MODAL LOGIN-->
    <div class="modal fade" id="login" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalCenterTitle" aria-hidden="true">
        <div class="modal-dialog modal modal-dialog-centered" role="document">
            <div class="modal-content bg-dark text-light">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <h3 class="modal-title display-6" id="exampleModalCenterTitle">Ingreso al sistema</h5>
                        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">                         
                        <span class="fa-layers fa-fw">
                            <i class="fas fa-circle" style="color:Tomato"></i>
                            <i class="fa-inverse fas fa-times" data-fa-transform="shrink-6"></i>
                        </span>
                    </button>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-8">
                            <form id="login1">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label for="recipient-name" class="col-form-label">Usuario</label>
                                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="usuario">
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label for="message-text" class="col-form-label">Contraseña</label>
                                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="contrasena">
                                </div>
                                <button class="btn btn-primary mx-4">Aceptar</button>
                                <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger mx-4" data-dismiss="modal" id="cancelar">Cancelar</button>
                            </form>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-CSXorXvZcTkaix6Yvo6HppcZGetbYMGWSFlBw8HfCJo=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-Q6E9RHvbIyZFJoft+2mJbHaEWldlvI9IOYy5n3zV9zzTtmI3UksdQRVvoxMfooAo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-wfSDF2E50Y2D1uUdj0O3uMBJnjuUD4Ih7YwaYd1iqfktj0Uod8GCExl3Og8ifwB6" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="js/logica.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Una manera simple de vaciarlos es establecer un valor vacío en los inputs.

```
$("#usuario, #contrasena").val("");
```

También puedes establecer un valor `null`:

```
$("#usuario, #contrasena").val(null);
```

Si además quieres que se vacíen al cancelar en vez de al cargar el modal, puedes hacerlo mediante el evento `click` del botón. Así no verás cargar los valores y después borrarse.

```
$("#cancelar").click(function(){
  $('#usuario, #contrasena').val("");
});
```

**Snippet on show:**

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#login').on('shown.bs.modal', function() {
        $('#usuario').focus();
        $("#usuario, #contrasena").val("");
    });
})
```

```html
<?php
 session_start();
?>
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<style>
    .fondo {
        background: url("img/02.jpg");
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        background-size: cover;
    }    
    .alto {
        height: 100vh;
    }
</style>
<head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <script defer src="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.6/js/all.js"></script>
    <!-- <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/2215372ade.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script> -->
</head>
<body>
    <!--PANTALLA INICIAL DEL SISTEMA-->
    <div class="container-fluid fondo">
        <div class="row alto align-items-center justify-content-center text-center text-ligth text-white">
            <div class="col-m-8">
                <div class="display-4">
                    <i class="fas fa-spinner fa-spin"></i>
                </div>
                <h1 class="display-4 my-3">SIGED</h1>
                <p class="lead mb-4">Sistema Integrado de Gestión Educacional</p>
                <hr class="bg-light">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-light mx-2" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#login">Ingresar</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- MODAL LOGIN-->
    <div class="modal fade" id="login" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalCenterTitle" aria-hidden="true">
        <div class="modal-dialog modal modal-dialog-centered" role="document">
            <div class="modal-content bg-dark text-light">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <h3 class="modal-title display-6" id="exampleModalCenterTitle">Ingreso al sistema</h5>
                        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">                         
                        <span class="fa-layers fa-fw">
                            <i class="fas fa-circle" style="color:Tomato"></i>
                            <i class="fa-inverse fas fa-times" data-fa-transform="shrink-6"></i>
                        </span>
                    </button>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-8">
                            <form id="login1">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label for="recipient-name" class="col-form-label">Usuario</label>
                                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="usuario">
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label for="message-text" class="col-form-label">Contraseña</label>
                                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="contrasena">
                                </div>
                                <button class="btn btn-primary mx-4">Aceptar</button>
                                <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger mx-4" data-dismiss="modal" id="cancelar">Cancelar</button>
                            </form>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-CSXorXvZcTkaix6Yvo6HppcZGetbYMGWSFlBw8HfCJo=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-Q6E9RHvbIyZFJoft+2mJbHaEWldlvI9IOYy5n3zV9zzTtmI3UksdQRVvoxMfooAo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-wfSDF2E50Y2D1uUdj0O3uMBJnjuUD4Ih7YwaYd1iqfktj0Uod8GCExl3Og8ifwB6" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="js/logica.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

**Snippet cancelar click event:**

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#login').on('shown.bs.modal', function() {
        $('#usuario').focus();
    });
    
    $("#cancelar").click(function(){
      $("#usuario, #contrasena").val("");
    });
});
```

```html
<?php
 session_start();
?>
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<style>
    .fondo {
        background: url("img/02.jpg");
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        background-size: cover;
    }    
    .alto {
        height: 100vh;
    }
</style>
<head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <script defer src="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.6/js/all.js"></script>
    <!-- <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/2215372ade.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script> -->
</head>
<body>
    <!--PANTALLA INICIAL DEL SISTEMA-->
    <div class="container-fluid fondo">
        <div class="row alto align-items-center justify-content-center text-center text-ligth text-white">
            <div class="col-m-8">
                <div class="display-4">
                    <i class="fas fa-spinner fa-spin"></i>
                </div>
                <h1 class="display-4 my-3">SIGED</h1>
                <p class="lead mb-4">Sistema Integrado de Gestión Educacional</p>
                <hr class="bg-light">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-light mx-2" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#login">Ingresar</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- MODAL LOGIN-->
    <div class="modal fade" id="login" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalCenterTitle" aria-hidden="true">
        <div class="modal-dialog modal modal-dialog-centered" role="document">
            <div class="modal-content bg-dark text-light">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <h3 class="modal-title display-6" id="exampleModalCenterTitle">Ingreso al sistema</h5>
                        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">                         
                        <span class="fa-layers fa-fw">
                            <i class="fas fa-circle" style="color:Tomato"></i>
                            <i class="fa-inverse fas fa-times" data-fa-transform="shrink-6"></i>
                        </span>
                    </button>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-8">
                            <form id="login1">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label for="recipient-name" class="col-form-label">Usuario</label>
                                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="usuario">
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label for="message-text" class="col-form-label">Contraseña</label>
                                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="contrasena">
                                </div>
                                <button class="btn btn-primary mx-4">Aceptar</button>
                                <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger mx-4" data-dismiss="modal" id="cancelar">Cancelar</button>
                            </form>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-CSXorXvZcTkaix6Yvo6HppcZGetbYMGWSFlBw8HfCJo=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-Q6E9RHvbIyZFJoft+2mJbHaEWldlvI9IOYy5n3zV9zzTtmI3UksdQRVvoxMfooAo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-wfSDF2E50Y2D1uUdj0O3uMBJnjuUD4Ih7YwaYd1iqfktj0Uod8GCExl3Og8ifwB6" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="js/logica.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

Una opción algo distinta es utilizar para limpiar el formulario etiquetas genéricas en lugar de ir directamente al campo en concreto en caso de que tu formulario crezca y así no tener que actualizar tu código en ese supuesto, pasándole un valor vacío del siguiente modo al input de tipo texto si que todos fueran de este tipo:

```
$('input[type=text').val('');
```

Si lo que necesitas es reestablecer todos y cada uno de los campos lo que puedes probar es, que "limpiará" todo el formulario independientemente del tipo de input de que se trate o el id/clase que le otorgues para controlar otro tipo de circunstancias:

```
$('form :input').val('');
```

Comment: ¿Puedes argumentar que tiene de diferente tu respuesta a la mía? A parte del selector que borrara todos los campos texto o todos los input del formulario cuando el esta buscando 2 concretos.

Comment: toda la razón que en debería desde el principio haber aclarado el porque de mi respuesta en distinción a la que tu ofrecias, que es perfectamente válida.

Answer (score 0):

podrias hacerlo con un trigger

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#login').on('shown.bs.modal', function() {
       $('#login1').trigger('reset');
       $('#usuario').focus();
    });
});
```